# Water trick, explanation needed

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, refraction

So I encountered this video [of glass changing colors when placed in water and outside of it](https://www.tiktok.com/@livmantel/video/7113372924890991874).
How is it explained by physics?

Video: Guy puts glass on table where is no water, and the glass appears to be white, but when put on the same table but with some water on it, the glass doesn't reflect(?) light and is transparent so you can see the table beneath it.

In case of reflection - if the reflected light is the cause behind this glass being white, why the reflection is why and not mirror-like?

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking without clicking on the link you provided. To make questions more accessible and guard against [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), please include all relevant information, such as a more detailed description of the effect you're talking about, in the question itself.

Comment: It Looks to me  like a case of total internal reflection as light goes from glass (n=1.5) to air (n=1.0) in the "lit" case and not in the "dark" case as light goes from glass to water (n=1.3). Is this your experiment? It would help to know where the light was. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection

Answer (score 1):

I found it interesting that the video shows the effect so clearly as I tried various permutations of lighting and table colour and the ones used in the video seemed to be amongst the best.

The TikTok video shows a tumbler full of water placed on a wooden table (left image) and then on a puddle of water on the table (right image).

[image]

The effect is not as clear on the stills but basically the clear water tumbler when standing on the wooden table becomes the colour of the table when it has a layer of water underneath it.

I reproduce the effect as shown below.

[image]

Image **1** shows an empty tumbler on a wooden table.

Image **2** shows the tumbler which has a void on its underside standing on the table but with a drop of water making contact between the table and the bottom of the tumbler.
Because the light has to go from the table through the water (refractive index, $\mu = 1.33$) and then into the glass ($\mu = 1.5$) rather than from air ($\mu = 1$) into glass ($\mu = 1.5$) more of the light is transmitted than reflected at the interface.

Image **3** shows the effect of filling the tumbler with water.
There is a greater contrast between the water drop and no water drop regions.

Image **4** has the whole of the base of the tumbler standing in water.
Being anxious to get reasonable images I only noticed the different regions $a,\,b,\,c$ and $d$ when I was processing the images.

[image]

Image **5** shows the bevel on the tumbler which was responsible for region $c$ in image **6**.

It then became clear to me that region $d$ showed a reflection of light from the bottom of the tumbler.

I suspected that it was total internal reflection at the air - outside surface of glass interface.

Image **7** shows what happened when I placed a finger outside the glass.
My finger was seen through the bevel region $c$ but note in region $d$.

Image **8** shows my finger touching the outside of the glass in region $d$ resulting in any reflection not being visible.

I conclude that the effect is due to the water layer providing improved coupling to allow more light to enter the tumbler and the tumbler with water in it acting as an optical fibre.